# Nested Custom Serializer Json4s

Tags: scala, json4s

I have a scenario like:

```
case class A (map: Map[String,Map[String,List[B]]])

case class B(s:String,t:Int)
```

I am using Json4s and I want to create custom serializers for both the classes and use class B serializer in class A custom serializer definition.